# Set a Template Variable Based on Breakpoint

Tags: templating

I have a requirement that a menu is open on wider breakpoints and closed on mobile breakpoints. To make it open i have a class i would toggle on my menu.

I can do this with JS but i get a FOUC on the menu on mobile, since it opens at first and then closes. So what i would ideally do is do this server side and exclude the class.

Is there some way with craft templates to set a variable containing the breakpoint or screen size?

Fx..

> {%set isMobileSize =  ??? %}

Ideally this would get the page size in the request and set this when rendering the page/template?

Comment: Just so I understand, is the question "Can I set a Twig variable to the browser's current screen size?"

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't set the menu to be "closed" initially with CSS on mobile breakpoints and then have it "open" on larger ones? That's usually a "mobile first" approach...

Comment: Yes thats the question in a way but i need to be able to quality > a size

Comment: In that case i have the reserve FOUC content problem where the menu appears closed and then open.